# Multiple highcharts at same page based on clientId value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, highcharts

Hello to everyone I drew a highstock chart with consuming rest api json and everything working properly.
But now I want to have multiple numbers of charts (based on `clientId`).I push array outside loop with (`cpu_usage`, `timestamp` and `clientID`). So is there anybody who knows how to create dynamically more  highcharts based on `clientID`?

Example:
If I have 3 `clientID` I need 3 highcharts with their `cpu_usage` and `timestamp`.

Rest api JSON: http://5ea073ff.ngrok.io/api/clients

Result: [image: result]

```
<div id="container"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript">

$.getJSON( "http://localhost:8000/api/devices", function( res) {


    var result= [];
    var clientNames = new Array();
    console.log(result);

  $.each( res, function(i) {
        var deviceNames=data[i].clientAllias;
        var clientId=data[i].clientId;
        clientNames.push(deviceNames);          
    $.each( data[i].clientData, function(a) {
        $.each( data[i].clientData[a], function(key, val) {
            clientId2=data[i].clientData[a].clientId
            var cpu=data[i].clientData[a].cpuUsage;
            var time_usages=data[i].clientData[a].timestamp;
            infos=[];
            infos.push(time_usages, cpu, clientId2);
            result.push(infos);

  });
  });
     });

    result.sort();

$(document).ready(function(){
        var dataObject = {
            marker: {
        states: {
            enabled: true,
        }
    },
        rangeSelector: {
            buttons: [{
                count: 1,
                type: 'minute',
                text: 'Sec'
            }, {
                count: 1,
                type: 'hour',
                text: 'Min'
            }, 
            {
                count: 1,
                type: 'day',
                text: 'Hours'
            },

            {
                type: 'all',
                text: 'All'

            }],
            title:'hours',
            inputEnabled: true,
            _selected: 1
        },


            title: {
                text: clientNames,
            },
          xAxis: {

    title: {
        enabled: true,
        text: 'CPU USAGE'
    },
    type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
               second: '%H:%M:%S',
               minute: '%H:%M',
               hour: '%H:%M',
               day: '%e. %b',
               week: '%e. %b',


            },


},
plotOptions: {
        series: {
            marker: {
                enabled: true,
                radius: 3,
                fillColor: '#007ab3',
            }
        }
    },

            series: [{
    name:"CPU USAGE",
   data: result,
    }],

            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container'
            }

        };

         var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart(dataObject);   
        //var chart = $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', dataObject);



    });
   });




</script>
```

Comment: I think your issue is that you are always rendering to one container `renderTo: 'container'`. Try something like: `renderTo: 'container'+clientId`.

Comment: I'm trying to collect clientId values **console.log(result[0][2]);** for variable which will i use in **renderTo: 'container'+clientId**  ,  but it shows me a error "Cannot read property '1' of undefined"  [link] https://imgur.com/a/JVhzHyP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map the data by clientId. Then each clientId can be mapped aswell to take the cpuUsage, timeStamp, clientId. You can make an array which each client has its own data from the previous map. Then you can append the chart like this

```
_.forEach(clients, function(client) {
$('<div class="chart">')
    .appendTo('#container')
    .highcharts({
        marker: {
            states: {
                enabled: true
            }
        },
        rangeSelector: {
            buttons: [{
                    count: 1,
                    type: "minute",
                    text: "Sec"
                },
                {
                    count: 1,
                    type: "hour",
                    text: "Min"
                },
                {
                    count: 1,
                    type: "day",
                    text: "Hours"
                },

                {
                    type: "all",
                    text: "All"
                }
            ],
            title: "hours",
            inputEnabled: true,
            _selected: 1
        },

        title: {
            text: client.name
        },
        xAxis: {
            title: {
                enabled: true,
                text: "CPU USAGE"
            },
            type: "datetime",
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                second: "%H:%M:%S",
                minute: "%H:%M",
                hour: "%H:%M",
                day: "%e. %b",
                week: "%e. %b",
                day: "%Y<br/>%b-%d"
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                marker: {
                    enabled: true,
                    radius: 3,
                    fillColor: "#007ab3"
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: "CPU USAGE",
            data: client.data.sort()
        }],

        chart: {
            renderTo: "container" + name
        }
    });
```

})

I Used lodash as helper for mapping the data, but you can use anything you want. I find it much easier for parsing data.

```
var mappedClients = _.map(_.uniqBy(data, "clientId"), "clientId"); <-- ALL UNIQUE CLIENTS
var clients = [];
_.forEach(mappedClients, function(clientId) {
    var tempClient = {
        name: clientId,
        data: []
    };
    _.forEach(data, function(tempData) { <--- MAPPING THROUGH ALL DATA TO FIND A MATCH FOR EACH UNIQUE CLIENT 
        if (clientId === tempData.clientId) {
            _.forEach(tempData.clientData, function(clientData) { <-- THEN MAP CLIENTDATA ARRAY OF THE CLIENT TO KEEP THE DATA THAT WE WANT
                tempClient.data.push(
                    [clientData.cpuUsage, clientData.timestamp, clientId]
                );
            })
        }
    });
    clients.push(tempClient);
});
```

**check a working jsfiddle example based on your info**
[Jsfiddle](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YOybOv?editors=1010)